# frontend and backend are running but getting error : " Connection refused "

Tags: configuration, load-balancing, haproxy

This is my haproxy config file looks like .

my frontend and backend servers are running , noerrors. port 8442 and 443 is linstening on haproxy server.

I am getting error Failed connect to bserverd1.dev.exa:443; Connection refused

how to resolve this problem .

```
global
  log         127.0.0.1 local2 info
  chroot      /var/lib/haproxy
  pidfile     /var/run/haproxy.pid
  maxconn     4000
  user        haproxy
  group       haproxy
  daemon
  tune.ssl.default-dh-param 2048
  stats socket /var/lib/haproxy/stats
defaults
  mode                    http
  log                     global
  option                  httplog
  option                  dontlognull
  option http-server-close
  option                  redispatch
  retries                 3
  timeout http-request    10s
  timeout queue           1m
  timeout connect         10s
  timeout client          1m
  timeout server          1m
  timeout http-keep-alive 10s
  timeout check           10s
  maxconn                 3000
  listen stats :8181
  stats enable
  stats hide-version
  stats realm Haproxy\ Statistics
  stats uri /
frontend port_8442
  bind *:8442 ssl crt-list /etc/haproxy/ssl/list/cert-list.txt
  reqadd X-Forwarded-Proto:\ https
  acl badmin path_reg -i ^/BAdmin.*$
  use_backend BAdmDev if { ssl_fc_sni bdev.dev.exa } badmin
  mode http
  option tcplog
frontend port_443
  bind *:443 ssl crt-list /etc/haproxy/ssl/list/cert-list.txt
  redirect scheme https if !{ ssl_fc }
  mode http
  acl Exten path_reg -i ^/BExten.*$
  use_backend BExtenDev if { ssl_fc_sni bdev.dev.exa } Exten
backend BAdmDev
  mode http
  balance roundrobin
  cookie SERVERID insert indirect nocache
  server bserverd1 bserverd1.dev.exa:8442 ssl check verify none cookie t1
  server bserverd2 bserverd2.dev.exa:8442 ssl check verify none cookie t2
backend BExtenDev
  redirect scheme https if !{ ssl_fc }
  mode http
  balance roundrobin
  option httpchk GET /BExtens
  cookie SERVERID insert indirect nocache
  server bserverd3 bserverd3.dev.exa:8442 ssl check verify none
  server bserverd4 bserverd4.dev.exa:8442 ssl check verify none `
```